# Keyes IR receiver with Arduino

Tags: arduino, wireless, infrared, digital-communications

I'm trying to learn how to connect an IR Receiver to an Arduino Uno. I got this IR receiver as a gift, and I'm having a hard time finding a spec. sheet anywhere online. The module looks like this:

[image]

This brick comes with three pins: an S (which I assume it stands for VSS, a - (GND) and another one that I have no idea if it should be connected to anything.

I was wondering if anybody has some experience with this module. I'm attempting to connect it to the Arduino Uno. 
Thanks much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://adhocnode.com/arduino-irrecv-module/) seems to have information:

- "-" is ground
- middle pin is +3.3V supply
- "S" is the signal output

Comment: thanks so much. I would vote your answer, but I need 15 of reputation. :)

Comment: Note that the solder pads are round except for one that is square - that means it's pin number 1, should you have a datasheet to compare to.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://arduinoinfo.mywikis.net/wiki/IR-RemoteControl) is a different version of the same receiver with additional info.

Comment: and this explains perfectly why answers should INCLUDE information, rather than link to it